# How to access detailed docstring in VSCode on Mac?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am unable to access detailed docstring of existing functions and methods in Python on Mac. It's working fine on another person's windows. I have attached both of the screenshots below. I am trying to achieve a detailed one.

**Screenshot of current Scenario**:
[image: Screenshot of current Scenario]

**Screenshot of what I am trying to achieve**
[image: Screenshot of what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: What language server are you using?

Comment: From where I can check that?

Comment: What is your `"python.jediEnabled"` and `"python.languageServer"` setting set to?